# How to add an element to every array of dimensional array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, element

How to add element to array of multiple dimensional array that will give me output like below code

Source code  :
see there are dynamic name $tgvalues['Name'] = calneder
                        product
                        financial tip 
                        health tips
                        personal event

```
          foreach($json as $templategroup => $tgvalues){
                  $templateval1 = "emailtemplates?expand=".$tgvalues['Name'];
                  $final1 = str_replace(' ','%20',trim($templateval1));
                  $path1 = constant('AMT_BASE_PATH');
                  $url1 = $path1.$final1;
                  $url1;
                  $ch1=curl_init();
                  curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_URL, $url1);
                  curl_setopt($ch1,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                  $buffer1 = curl_exec($ch1);
                  curl_close($ch1); 
                  $json1 = json_decode($buffer1, true);
                  $newarray =array('templatename' =>$tgvalues['Name']);
                  print_r(array_merge($json1,$newarray));
                  if (empty($buffer1)){
                      print "There are some problem";
                  } else {
                      $fetchtemplatename1 = Resources_Customers_Customer::fetchtemplategroups();
                      $insert1 = array_diff_assoc($json1, $fetchtemplatename1);

                      //print_r($insert1);
                      $arr_tampgrop =array();
                      foreach($json1 as $key1 => $value1)
                                {


                                    $arr_tampgrop[] =array('Id'=>$value1['Id'],'Name'=>$value1['Name'],'Subject'=>$value1['Subject'],'Body'=>$value1['Body'],'Href'=>$value1['Href']);


                                }
                                //$arrtempname = array($tgvalues['Name']);
                                $arraypush = array_push($arr_tampgrop,$arrtempname["templatename"] = $tgvalues['Name']);
                                print_r($arraypush); 

                              }

                            }
```

in the source code I am use array_merge ,see line print_r(array_merge($json1,$newarray));

This code, i am getting now

```
      Array
(
      [0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 1
        [Name] => Merry Christmas                                   
        [Subject] => Merry Christmas
        [Body] => This is the body
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 2
        [Name] => Happy 4th of July                                 
        [Subject] => Happy 4th!
        [Body] => This is the body of a July message
        [Href] => 
    )

[templatename] => Calendar                                          
)
 3Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 3
        [Name] => New Product 1                                     
        [Subject] => See this new product
        [Body] => This is the body of a one new product
        [Href] =>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 9
        [Name] => Drip product 1                                    
        [Subject] => Drip new product 1 subject
        [Body] => Drip new product 1 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 10
        [Name] => Drip product 2                                    
        [Subject] => Drip new product 2 subject
        [Body] => Drip new product 2 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 11
        [Name] => Drip product 3                                    
        [Subject] => Drip new product 3 subject
        [Body] => Drip new product 3 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[templatename] => Products                                          
)
5Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 4
        [Name] => Happy Birthday                                    
        [Subject] => Happy Birthday
        [Body] => This is the body of a birthday card
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 5
        [Name] => Happy Anniversary                                 
        [Subject] => Happy Anniversary
        [Body] => This is the body of a anniversary card
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 6
        [Name] => After Days 0                                      
        [Subject] => We are glad you joined x0 days ago
        [Body] => This is the body of a join x0 days ago card
        [Href] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 7
        [Name] => After Days 1                                      
        [Subject] => We are glad you joined x1 days ago
        [Body] => This is the body of a join x1 days ago card
        [Href] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 8
        [Name] => After Days 2                                      
        [Subject] => We are glad you joined x2 days ago
        [Body] => This is the body of a join x2 days ago card
        [Href] => 
    )

[templatename] => Personal Events                                   
  )
      6Array
         (
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 12
        [Name] => Drip health tip 1                                 
        [Subject] => Drip health tip 1 subject
        [Body] => Drip health tip 1 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (    
        [templatename] => Health Tips
        [Id] => 13
        [Name] => Drip health tip 2                                 
        [Subject] => Drip health tip 2 subject
        [Body] => Drip health tip 2 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Health Tips
        [Id] => 14
        [Name] => Drip health tip 3                                 
        [Subject] => Drip health tip 3 subject
        [Body] => Drip health tip 3 body
        [Href] => 
    )


      )
       4Array
        (
      [0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 15
        [Name] => Drip financial tip 1                              
        [Subject] => Drip financial tip 1 subject
        [Body] => Drip financial tip 1 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 16
        [Name] => Drip financial tip 2                              
        [Subject] => Drip financial tip 2 subject
        [Body] => Drip financial tip 2 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 17
        [Name] => Drip financial tip 3                              
        [Subject] => Drip financial tip 3 subject
        [Body] => Drip financial tip 3 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[templatename] => Financial Tips                                    
  )
```

So i Want result like this below . is it possible or not

```
      Array
(
      [0] => Array
    (   
        [templatename] => Calendar
        [Id] => 1
        [Name] => Merry Christmas                                   
        [Subject] => Merry Christmas
        [Body] => This is the body
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Calendar
        [Id] => 2
        [Name] => Happy 4th of July                                 
        [Subject] => Happy 4th!
        [Body] => This is the body of a July message
        [Href] => 
    )


)
 3Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Products
        [Id] => 3
        [Name] => New Product 1                                     
        [Subject] => See this new product
        [Body] => This is the body of a one new product
        [Href] =>
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 9
        [templatename] => Products
        [Name] => Drip product 1                                    
        [Subject] => Drip new product 1 subject
        [Body] => Drip new product 1 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Products
        [Id] => 10
        [Name] => Drip product 2                                    
        [Subject] => Drip new product 2 subject
        [Body] => Drip new product 2 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Products
        [Id] => 11
        [Name] => Drip product 3                                    
        [Subject] => Drip new product 3 subject
        [Body] => Drip new product 3 body
        [Href] => 
    )


)
 5Array
(
   [0] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Personal Events
        [Id] => 4
        [Name] => Happy Birthday                                    
        [Subject] => Happy Birthday
        [Body] => This is the body of a birthday card
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
     (    
        [templatename] => Personal Events
        [Id] => 5
        [Name] => Happy Anniversary                                 
        [Subject] => Happy Anniversary
        [Body] => This is the body of a anniversary card
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Personal Events
        [Id] => 6
        [Name] => After Days 0                                      
        [Subject] => We are glad you joined x0 days ago
        [Body] => This is the body of a join x0 days ago card
        [Href] => 
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Personal Events 
        [Id] => 7
        [Name] => After Days 1                                      
        [Subject] => We are glad you joined x1 days ago
        [Body] => This is the body of a join x1 days ago card
        [Href] => 
    )

[4] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Personal Events
        [Id] => 8
        [Name] => After Days 2                                      
        [Subject] => We are glad you joined x2 days ago
        [Body] => This is the body of a join x2 days ago card
        [Href] => 
    )


  )
      6Array
         (
[0] => Array
    (

        [templatename] => Health Tips
        [Id] => 12
        [Name] => Drip health tip 1                                 
        [Subject] => Drip health tip 1 subject
        [Body] => Drip health tip 1 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Health Tips
        [Id] => 13
        [Name] => Drip health tip 2                                 
        [Subject] => Drip health tip 2 subject
        [Body] => Drip health tip 2 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Health Tips
        [Id] => 14
        [Name] => Drip health tip 3                                 
        [Subject] => Drip health tip 3 subject
        [Body] => Drip health tip 3 body
        [Href] => 
    )


      )
     4Array
      (
   [0] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Financial Tips
        [Id] => 15
        [Name] => Drip financial tip 1                              
        [Subject] => Drip financial tip 1 subject
        [Body] => Drip financial tip 1 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Financial Tips
        [Id] => 16
        [Name] => Drip financial tip 2                              
        [Subject] => Drip financial tip 2 subject
        [Body] => Drip financial tip 2 body
        [Href] => 
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [templatename] => Financial Tips
        [Id] => 17
        [Name] => Drip financial tip 3                              
        [Subject] => Drip financial tip 3 subject
        [Body] => Drip financial tip 3 body
        [Href] => 
    )


  )
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see you'll want to change the line

```
$arr_tampgrop[] =array('Id'=>$value1['Id'],'Name'=>$value1['Name'],'Subject'=>$value1['Subject'],'Body'=>$value1['Body'],'Href'=>$value1['Href']);
```

to be

```
$arr_tampgrop[] =array('templatename'=>$tgvalues['Name'],'Id'=>$value1['Id'],'Name'=>$value1['Name'],'Subject'=>$value1['Subject'],'Body'=>$value1['Body'],'Href'=>$value1['Href']);
```

and remove any line that adds templatename where you dont want it to be, such as

```
$newarray =array('templatename' =>$tgvalues['Name']);
print_r(array_merge($json1,$newarray));
```

&

```
$arraypush = array_push($arr_tampgrop,$arrtempname["templatename"] = $tgvalues['Name']);
```

The code was adding on the template name at the end of each array instead of as a part of the array. It also prints the array more than necessary so they can be commented out so that the output is easier to read for you.

Comment: Yes, you are right So how can I do this. be using array_push I got o/p : 35644 rather then addition of array.

Comment: Just remove your array_push and use print_r($arr_tampgrop)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) to accomplish this. It allows you to apply a function to every element of any array. In your case you could add an element to each sub array, by applying array_map to the parent array.

quick example (may need to tweak to your needs)

```
$newArray = array_map(
     function($subArr) use ($tgvalues) { return $subArr['templatename'] = $tgvalues['Name']; },
     $json1
);
```

The callback function only has access to the keys and values of the array it is working on. To use a defined variable in the callback use `use ($var)`

Comment: it say undefind $tgvalues['Name'] like in place return $subArr['templatename'] = $templateName; as the value coming dynamically  $templateName = $tgvalues['Name']

Comment: @smartdeveloper Oh yeah, you have to use `use` syntax, I'll update.

Answer (score 0):

On taking the value of templatename in array like array that I want to

merge with element i.e Calendar,health Tips , Products etc.

Then in foreach taking all values of child array and merge both array

```
$arr_tampgrop[] = array_merge($arrgroup,$value1); 

in print_r(arr_tampgrop); result is obtained.


$arrgroup = array("templatename" => $tgvalues['Name']);
                    $arr_tampgrop =array();
                       foreach($json1 as $key1 => $value1)
                                {
                                $arr_tampgrop[] = array_merge($arrgroup,$value1);
                                }
```